# PHP: text fil esentence iterator

Tags: php, parsing, text, stream

I would like to ask you about some known PHP libraries which may help me to parse `*.txt` files for sentences.
I have to parse too large text files, so I decided to make a stream parser (sentence by sentence).

I thought that it would be pretty to iterate file by sentences, something like:

```
foreach (new SentenceIterator("./data/huge.txt") as $sentence)
{
    // do something...
}
```

Main idea is that file should be load to the memory completely.

What I have tried:

```
$f = fopen("./data/huge.txt", "r");
$dataBytes = 64;
$buffer = '';

while (!feof($f))
{
    $data = fread($f, $dataBytes);
    $dotPosition = strpos($data, '.');

    if (false !== $dotPosition)
    {
        $sentence = $buffer . substr($data, 0, $dotPosition);
        // correct cursor position
        fseek($f, -1 * $dotPosition, SEEK_CUR);
        // clear buffer
        $buffer = '';
        continue;
    }

    $buffer .= $data;
}
```

But in this case I get corrupted (lopped) sentences.

Could someone suggest me some existing libraries or maybe how to fix my code?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for inconvenience,

After some digging I have found solution which is... Spl lib..

Iterator called `SplFileObject` which implements `Iterator`, `RecursiveIterator` and `SeekableIterator`. And it allows read file line by line.

Updates and worked code is:

```
$file = new SplFileObject('./data/test.txt');
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY);
$buffer = '';

foreach ($file as $lineNumber => $line)
{
    $dotPos = strpos($line, '.');
    if (false !== $dotPos)
    {
        $sentence = $buffer . substr($line, 0, $dotPos);
        echo $sentence . "\n";
        $buffer = substr($line, $dotPos);
        continue;
    }
    $buffer .= $line;
}
```